# any way of iterating over __slots__ and dynamically assign values?

Tags: python, slots

I'm making a framework for an agent based model and I have a class called agents.  Since there's going to be thousands of agents in the simulation, I want to use the __ slots__, which will replace the default __ dict__ and reduce memory consumption.  I have my code structured so that it gets the agent's parameter from a data table and I want to assign the values stored in the table to an attribute with the table's header name.

If the following is the data table,

```
|  agent_name  |  location  |    attr1    |    attr2   |
|--------------|------------|-------------|------------|
|  agent smith |    NY      |  some value | some value |
|  Neo         |    NY      |  some value | some value |
| Morpheus     |    Zion    |  some value | some value |
```

then if I create the 3 agents, I want all of them to have a .agent_name, .location, .attr1, and .attr2 attributes.

```
# illustration of what I want
header_of_table = ["agent_name", "location", "attr1", "attr2"]

class agent:
    __slots__ = header_of_table
    def __init__(self, values_in_row):
        # what I ideally want, I know this syntax doesnt work, but this is to get the idea across
        for slotted_attribute, value in zip(self.__slots__, values_in_row):
            self.slotted_attribute = value
```

I know you can use the .eval method inside the for loop, but I don't find that clean and I feel like there has to be a better way. I'm wondering if there's a way to iterate over the slots and assign value to each attributes.

Comment: There is "setattr".

Comment: Should probably read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots It says for example that your class needs to inherit from `object`. Also it's `__slots__` not `__slot__`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you do not need to explicitly inherit from `object` in Python 3.

Comment: @mandera yup, I had slots in the first paragraph, but for the rest it was slot.  I replaced all those typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few pointers:

- <strike>When using `__slots__` you need to inherit from `object`.</strike> 
  <sup>Python 2</sup>
- A class should always be capitalized.
- You can use `setattr` as Michael wrote in a comment.
- It's called `__slots__` not `__slot__`.

Here's a working example based on your code:

```
# illustration of what I want
header_of_table = ["agent_name", "location", "attr1", "attr2"]

class Agent:
    __slots__ = header_of_table
    def __init__(self, values_in_row):
        for i, slot in enumerate(self.__slots__):
            self.__setattr__(slot, values_in_row[i])

agent = Agent(["foo", "bar", "yellow", "green"])
print(agent.agent_name, agent.location, agent.attr1, agent.attr2)

>>> foo bar yellow green
```

**Edit for comment:**
If I understand you correctly then I would do something like this to avoid polluting the global scope.

slotheaders.py:

```
class SlotHeaders:
    __slots__ = ["agent_name", "location", "attr1", "attr2"]
```

agent.py:

```
from slotheaders import SlotHeaders

class Agent(SlotHeaders):
    def __init__(self, values_in_row):
        for i, slot in enumerate(self.__slots__):
            self.__setattr__(slot, values_in_row[i])

agent = Agent(["foo", "bar", "yellow", "green"])
print(agent.agent_name, agent.location, agent.attr1, agent.attr2)
```

Comment: Inheriting from `object` is only a thing in Python 2. In Python 3, that happens automatically, you don't need to specify it unless you need backwards compatibility with Python 2 (and you probably don't, by now).

Comment: I copied pasted from an editor so I didn't notice that I forgot to capitalize the class name, thank you for pointing that out, I'll make sure to correct it.

Comment: @Mandera I'm satisfied with the current answer, but the `header_of_row` is in the global scope and if I wanted to restrict the scope, then I would need to nest the Agent class inside a function that can store the `header_of_row`. This meta function's purpose is solely to assign header_of_row to `__slots__`.  This is the only thing that I can come up with to restrict the scope, is there a better way to assign a variable to `__slots__`?  Or should I create a new question because it's different from the original question?

Comment: @KukaiNakahata Edited my answer, what do you think?

Comment: @Mandera that is an elegant solution and it’s better than wrapping it in a function. Thank you, it’s a great answer.